# Non-Linear ordinary differential equation involving first derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Kindly help me in solving non-linear ODE:
$$y'^2+y^2+4=0$$

Comment: Welcome tu MSE. Before posting questions you should take a look at our community guidelines on how to write better questions. Let us know that you've tried to solve the problem and post your solution even if it's not correct or you're stuck somewhere

Comment: How peculiar, the LHS is always positive; so no real solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $y=2\sinh u$ therefore $$4u'^2\cosh^2u+4+4\sinh^2u=0$$which means that $$4u'^2\cosh^2u+4\cosh^2u=0$$since $\cosh(.)$ is always positive we obtain $$u'^2+1=0$$which has no real answer, but if whole the complex plane is included then$$u'=\begin{cases}i& ,x\in S\\-i& ,x\notin S\end{cases}$$where $i=\sqrt {-1}$ and at least one of $S$ or $S^c$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb N$ (you don't need to mind this constraint so much, just choose $S$ so that $u$ is integrable). One answer is $$u=\begin{cases}ix& ,x\in S\\-ix& ,x\notin S\end{cases}$$which leads to $$y=\begin{cases}i\sin x& ,x\in S\\-i\sin x& ,x\notin S\end{cases}$$